# Do data models define the logical split between modules in a Prism application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

With some background on MVVM, I’m moving to Prism now for a large-scale application. I’ve read and—mostly—understood the excellent [Developer’s Guide to Prism](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42572).

What eludes me is: where do I logically separate my application into various models? It seems that different data sources (or models) dictate this, but I haven’t found a solid statement.

In my case, I’ve got a single data source: a data base containing a multitude of entries but in a single table, translating into a single object type. However, I’d like to have various entirely different visual representations of the data, depending on what the user wants to do with it. Are these representations better implemented as different modules or as different views within the same module? My feeling is that it’s the latter, since I can’t see how using the same data model over various modules would be implemented MVVM-wise, but I’d like to see it confirmed by the experts out there.

This question is somewhat similar to [Where does the data model go in a Prism app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893482/where-does-the-data-model-go-in-a-prism-app), but not entirely the same…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these representations better implemented as different modules or as different views within the same module?

Only you as a developer or architect could decide this. But I would also say the latter, i.e. different views within the same module.

A `Prism` module is nothing but a "loosely coupled functional unit". This is not the same thing as a different visual representation of the same (or almost the same) data.

Even a single view can be implemented to display several different visual representations of the same underlying data so you certainly don't need several modules to be able to this. So you should probably start with a single module. You can always add additional modules later on if you need to for some reason.

Comment: That’s right, thanks for the heads up! What’s important at this early stage is to keep modularity and extensibility in mind, so I’ll indeed implement a single module and put the infrastructure in place.

Comment: Oops, my bad—I had accepted it, but not voted on it. Thanks for the reminder!